# Why can't I read in my input value and display the alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I've looked this up and tried it out but it isn't working.  If the user submits `a` in the input field, then it should alert `it works` but for some reason it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  var $list, $newItemForm;
  $list = $('ul');
  $newItemForm = $("newItemForm");

  $newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // var text = $('input:text').val();
    var text = $('itemField').val();
    console.log(text);
    $list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    // $('input:text').val('');

    if (text == "a") {
      alert("it works");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="newItemForm">
  <input type="text" id="itemField" placeholder="item" />
  <input type="submit" id="add" value="add" />
</form>
```

Comment: Should be $("#newItemForm"); if you want to select element with id and all the others you are selecting in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to prefix `#` in the selector while referencing the form (`$("newItemForm")`) and input value (`$('itemField').val()`) in variables:

```js
$(function() {
  var $list, $newItemForm;
  $list = $('ul');
  $newItemForm = $("#newItemForm");

  $newItemForm.on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // var text = $('input:text').val();
      var text = $('#itemField').val(); 
      console.log(text);
      $list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
      // $('input:text').val('');

      if(text == "a") {
          alert("it works");
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="newItemForm">
    <input type="text" id="itemField" placeholder="item"/>
    <input type="submit" id="add" value="add"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Man, it's always the tiny things that stump me for the longest.  Thank you, Mamun.

Comment: @sp92, you are most welcome....yes, it is natural to miss things even though they are tiny....:)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the selectors for "newItemForm" and "itemField".

In jQuery, when you want to select elements by ID you need to prepend the # character.

The code should be as follows:

```
$(function() {
var $list, $newItemForm;
$list = $('ul');
$newItemForm = $("#newItemForm"); // Remember to use # to select by ID.

$newItemForm.on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get value from item field.
    var text = $('#itemField').val(); // Use # here as well.
    // Clear the item field.
    $('#itemField').val('');
    console.log(text);
    $list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');

    if(text == "a") {
        alert("it works");
    }
});

});
```

If you don't use #, jQuery expects what follows to be an element type, for instance ul or span or the like. If you want to select by class you need to prepend a . in front of the class name, for instance ".classname".

I hope this helps.